# Listar arquivos com data utilizando PHP-mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, file-upload

Olá. Sou iniciante na programação e estou desenvolvendo um projeto. Eu já realizei o código para fazer o upload do arquivo, agora eu gostaria de listar estes arquivos em uma tabela e que nela mostre uma coluna com o nome arquivo e outra com coluna a data anexada(conforme a hora que consta no banco de dados):

```
<body>
    <h3>Arquivos Adicionados:</h3>
    <?php
        $path = "upload/";
        $diretorio = dir($path);

        echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
        echo "<table class='table'>";
        echo "<thead class='thead-dark'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Nome</th>";
        echo "<th>Data/Hora</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";

        while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){
            echo "<tbody>"; 
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href='".$path.$arquivo."' style='text-decoration:none'>".$arquivo."</a></td>";
            echo "<td>" ??? "</td>";                
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>"; 
        }
        echo "</table><br>";

    $diretorio -> close();
    ?>
    <a href="add_arquivos.php"><button class="btn btn-primary">Inserir +</button></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando a DATA do filesistem, ou seja a data que o servidor criou o arquivo neste método não é possivel ja que a função dir() retorna somente os nomes dos arquivos.
Você precisaria fazer:

```
echo "<td>";
        echo date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($arquivo));
        echo "</td>";
```

em substituição a:

```
echo "<td>" ??? "</td>";
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, Romeu. Eu acrescentei ao código o $path e ficou assim: echo "<td>". date ("d/m/Y", filemtime($path.$arquivo))."</td>";

Porque estava me retornando a data January 01 1970. Mas agora deu certinho. Valeu mesmo

Comment: Sim, bem lembrado, havia esquecido de acrescentar o path para os arquivos.... Ai ele devolte sempre 0 pois o arquivo pode ser inexistente.....